# Google gmail block for no ptr of 4to6 ip address

Tags: gmail, spf, ptr-record, ndr

When mail server got only ipv4 address and enabled 4to6 interface, gmail server block mail because of no ptr record of 4to6 address.
Why...?

Isn't 4to6 address not global standard...?

Answer (score 0):

4to6 is a way [to allow IPv4-only machines to access IPv6-only content](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-sun-v4tov6-00). It's wholly inappropriate for a mail server to use.

Comment: I mean why google don't consider 4to6 address is not public ipv6 address.